# Multi pages API slows down loading

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am using this [FREE NBA API](https://rapidapi.com/theapiguy/api/free-nba?endpoint=apiendpoint_a70b696d-ffe8-4b11-8f6b-8a7d8ea327aa) for a technical test. Loading the teams was easy and simple. The problem is that I had to display all the players for a specific team. The team doesn't return the players but only team info:

```
"data":[
0:{
"id":1
"abbreviation":"ATL"
"city":"Atlanta"
"conference":"East"
"division":"Southeast"
"full_name":"Atlanta Hawks"
"name":"Hawks"
}
1:{...}
2:{...}
]
```

So I have to get all the players which are returned in several pages (approximately 35)  of maximum 100 results. I came up with this code which works but sometimes it takes longer and I would like to try something else.

```
func loadPlayers(team:Team, pages: Int?, completion: @escaping (_ error:Error?, _ players:[Player]) -> ()){
        var players = [Player]()
        let rest = RestManager()
        for (key, value) in headers {
            rest.requestHttpHeaders.add(value: value, forKey: key)
        }
        //loop thought the API pages this is o(n) but the API is really badly designed as teams doesen't have an array with the players
        for page in 1..<pages! {
            rest.makeRequest(withEndPoint: "players?per_page=100&page=\(page)", withHttpMethod: .get) { (result) in
                guard let response = result.response else {return}
                if response.httpStatusCode == 200 {
                    guard let data = result.data else {return}
                    print(data.printJSON())
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    guard let playerResult = try? decoder.decode(PlayerData.self, from: data) else { return }
                    for player in playerResult.data {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if player.team?.abbreviation == team.abbreviation {
                                players.append(player)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    guard let error = result.error else {return}
                    completion(error, [])
                }
                completion(nil, players)
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my data model:

```
struct PlayerData : Decodable {
    var data:[Player]
    var meta:MetaDataPlayer
}
struct Player : Decodable {
    var id:Int?
    var first_name:String?
    var last_name:String?
    var height_feet:Int?
    var height_inches:Int?
    var weight_pounds:Int?
    var position:String?
    var team:Team?
}

struct MetaDataPlayer : Decodable {
    var total_pages:Int? // needed to loop through all pages of the API
    var current_page:Int?
    var next_page:Int?
    var per_page:Int?
    var total_count:Int?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different approaches you can take when trying to consume large paged data sets. Two that are likely to see the largest performance improvements are:

**Make your API calls in parallel.**

Each of your calls is dependent on waiting for the previous call to complete. As the number of pages increases, so does your total time. An error in one call will delay every future call. By splitting out the calls into parallel calls, you remove this bottleneck. You may run into rate limiting issues, so the number and speed at which you can make multiple queries will require some experimentation.

**Pre-fetch pages before you need them.**

Paged results are typically used when a subset of the full data can be used from an otherwise large data set. If your particular usage requires the full dataset before you can perform operations on it, consider starting the fetch process at an earlier time in the background, before the user needs it. This way, the bottlenecking API call is done by the time the user needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `DispatchSemaphore` which gives us the ability to control access to a shared resource by multiple threads:

```
 func loadPlayersWithConcurrentCalls(team:Team, completion: @escaping (_ error:Error?, _ players:[Player]) -> ()){
        //Create a dispatch queue
        var players = [Player]()
        var playerData:PlayerData?
        self.loadPlayersData { (error, data) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }else{
                guard let data = data else {return}
                playerData = data
            }
            let rest = RestManager()
            for (key, value) in self.headers {
                rest.requestHttpHeaders.add(value: value, forKey: key)
            }
            //added semaphore and backgroundQueue to manage multiple api calls
            let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "requests")
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
            backgroundQueue.async {
                for page in 1..<playerData!.meta.total_pages! {
                    semaphore.wait()
                    rest.makeRequest(withEndPoint: "players?per_page=100&page=\(page)", withHttpMethod: .get) { (result) in
                        guard let response = result.response else {return}
                        if response.httpStatusCode == 200 {
                            guard let data = result.data else {return}
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            guard let playerResult = try? decoder.decode(PlayerData.self, from: data) else { return }
                            players.append(contentsOf: playerResult.data)
                                semaphore.signal()
                        }else{
                            print(response.httpStatusCode)
                            completion(error,[])
                        }
                        completion(nil,players)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I really like the result:

[image]