# Using a semaphore to throttle latest DispatchQueue

Tags: swift

Let's say I want to use one DispatchQueue to execute tasks on a shared resource. Those tasks are expensive but can be **skipped (canceled)**. I would like only to run the latest task as soon as a semaphore becomes available.

I could throttle tasks using the Combine framework for an interval of time:

```swift
throttle(for: interval, scheduler: myDispatchQueue, latest: true)
```

Is it possible to throttle using a Semaphore instead of a fixed time interval?

Comment: check if this answer to my own question solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122415/multi-pages-api-slows-down-loading

Comment: This is also a good reading but I am not sure it is applicable to what you are trying to achieve. https://medium.com/@roykronenfeld/semaphores-in-swift-e296ea80f860

Comment: If you have dispatch queue and you only want to run the latest, I'm not sure why one would reach for a semaphore. Just keep reference to the last task (e.g. the `DispatchWorkItem`) and `cancel` it before submitting another. It won't stop current one that is already running (unless you manually test for `isCancelled`), but if it hasn't started yet, it will cancel it. You can use same pattern for operations, too. But no need for semaphores, though.

Comment: The reason I want to use a semaphore is that the task will signal completion on a separate queue. I want to make sure the task is fully executed before I allow for another task to start. That said, I think I should rethink the architecture of the app based on the feedback I received in the comments. Thanks.